# Python Subprocess' Popen class fails to execute script with sudo passwordless access via cron job

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron, subprocess

I have a bash script that has to execute as another user from a python application. To do this, I have setup sudo access for the script, runme.sh, using visudo and granted explicit access to for acctA to run as otherAcct. If I run the python script from acctA, it executes runme.sh as expected but if I schedule in a crontab runme.sh never executes. What am I missing?

visudo (sudoers):

`acctA ALL = (otherAcct) NOPASSWD: /home/otherAcct/someapp/runme.sh`

In the python application, I am using subprocess.Popen to run then monitor stdout and print to the log. Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import threading
import inspect
import time
import datetime

try:
    print(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%c') + ' - Starting test. ')
    clean_file = "/tmp/testworkfile.txt"
    exec_command = ["sudo", "-u", "otherAcct", "/home/otherAcct/someapp/runme.sh", "-f", clean_file]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(exec_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while proc.poll() == None:
        #logging - print for now
        print('out: ' + proc.stdout.readline())
    print(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%c') + ' - Test complete. ')
except:
    print('Error: {0}'.format(str(sys.exc_info())))
```

runme.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
thislog=/home/otherAcct/someapp/someapp.log
echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%H:%M:%S` - executing runme.sh..." >> $thislog
# reading passed arguments
RUN_FILE=""
while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
        -f|--file)      # file, file passed in with files to be deleted
        RUN_FILE="$2"
        shift
        ;;
        *)
                        # unknown argument, intentionally blank
        ;;
esac
shift
done
# source otherAcct profile to be sure env is set
source /home/otherAcct/.bash_profile
# logging
echo "Check/verify user: $(whoami) " >> $thislog
echo "RUN_FILE input param: $RUN_FILE " >> $thislog
if [[ ! -z $RUN_FILE ]]; then
while IFS='' read -r fline || [[ -n "$fline" ]]; do
echo "deleting file: $fline " >> $thislog
rm $fline
done < "$RUN_FILE"
#
# end CHECK_RUN_FILE
else
echo "$RUN_FILE not found, exitting. "
fi
echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%H:%M:%S` - runme.sh complete" >> $thislog
```

Comment: Which user's `crontab` are you using? How about scheduling in grid's crontab from the beginning.

Comment: As an aside, the `while proc.poll() == None:` tends to lose data left in the pipe when the program exits. You should just do `for line in proc.stdout:` ... I've seen this broken way of reading stdout several times lately, does it come from some example?

Comment: Nope, doesn't really come from an example, just reading the docs. If I remember correctly, if poll() returns a return code then the process has completed execution. This is just a smoke test for my test script to reproduce the behavior, in my application script I am queing stdout and reading the output on a set interval in an async manner. Good point about the data loss though, it didn't occur to me.

Comment: I mistakenly left grid in there; but to answer the question, the second account, AcctA, has to kick off my application script. It's doing system maintenance and this particular function has to be ran from the grid (otherAcct) because of it's function, but it has to be in order with the application and AcctA is managing that process.

Comment: remove unrelated code: create a simple script (one-line) (make sure it works e.g., `echo hello world`), add it to sudoers (make sure `sudo /path/to/script` runs without a password), create a minimal Python script that runs it (make sure that Python script works), put Python script into crontab -- provide the error that you get.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. As @J.F.Sebastian suggested, a couple of days ago I cut everything down to a "Hello World" bash script and a minimal python program to call the script and still the hello world script fails to execute. I am going back to verify that stdout and stderr have no messages being output. I am starting to think TTY is the problem; this machine requires TTY and I think cron executes without it. Unfortunately, for the sake of security, I can't disable TTY.